# How to upload a list of employees as csv file to s3 without creating a csv file locally?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I have a list of data `List<Employee> employeeList`

I actually have the data as a text file containing JSON objects stored in s3(provided below a sample file).

```
{"Id":"ab12","firstName":"abc","lastName":"xyz"}
{"Id":"pq34","firstName":"pqr","lastName":"mn"}
```

I am able to read and store in list using this code snippet:

```
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3BucketName, fileKey)); 
S3ObjectInputStream s3Stream = s3Object.getObjectContent(); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Stream, StringUtils.UTF8)); 
List<Employee> employeeList=null; 
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  Employee employee = objectMapper.readValue(line, Employee.class);
  employeeList.add(employee);
}
```

I created a class Employee is as provided below:

```
public class Employee {
    String Id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

I don't want to create any file locally. I want to write my data to S3 Bucket as a .csv file directly as below.(where name is `firstName+lastName`)

```
Id     Name
----------------
ab12   abc xyz  
pq34   pqr mn
```

One thing I came across is that we can write data as InputStream and then pass it to -PutObjectRequest. But InputStream also takes filepath I don't want to create temp files .

```
PutObjectRequest putObj = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, KeyName, inputStream, metadata); 
s3client.putObject(putObj);
```

Another doubt is also regarding the format of csv file uploaded is required like the above format. I've also come across `CSV writer` but i am not sure how to use it.

Can somebody please help me with above problem and provide sample code snippets if possible?

Comment: can you please post some more code on what your CSV data is currently in? A string? How are you trying to create the input stream?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I have modified the question accordingly. It is not CSV data currently, i want to store it in s3 as CSV. Currently, it's in JSON which i have stored in list. Thanks!

Comment: So your question actually is: how can I upload the list of employees as a CSV to S3 without creating a CSV file?

Comment: yes!! @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: can you share your solution?